# How to get span dynamic value inside li ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My ASPX code looks like this:

```
<ul id="userlist">
    <a class="s-test">
        <li>
            <span id="userlistspan" class="tt-User" value="1">Cardiologist</span>
            <span id="userlistspan1" class="tt-Userss">SPECIALITY</span>
        </li>
    </a>
    <a class="s-test">
        <li>
            <span id="userlistspan" class="tt-User" value="2">Cardio</span>
            <span id="userlistspan1" class="tt-Userss">SPECIALITY</span>
        </li> 
    </a>
</ul>
```

The jQuery I have tried is like this:

```
$('#userlist li #userlistspan').click(function () {
    $('#txtSearch').val($(this).text());
})
//here am getting text like Cardio
```

How can I get value like `value=2` from that `span`?

Comment: Your HTML is completely invalid. 1) you cannot have an `a` element as a direct child of a `ul`. The `li` must be the child element. 2) You have duplicate `id` attributes. 3) `span` elements do not have a `value` attribute 4) the `a` element must have either an `href` or `name` attribute.

Comment: $('#userlistspan').attr('value');

Comment: 'userlistspan' always return first attr value.

Comment: yes its displaying always 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is completely invalid for several reasons:

- you cannot have an `a` element as a direct child of a `ul`. The `li` must be the child element.
- You have duplicate `id` attributes when the `id` should be unique in same document, use classes to group elements instead.
- `span` elements do not have a `value` attribute, if you want to store custom data with an element, use the `data-*` attribute.
- the `a` element must have either an `href` or `name` attribute, however their use in this case seems redundant so you can remove them.

You need to fix all those issues first:

```
<ul id="userlist">
    <li>
        <span class="userlistspan tt-User" data-value="1">Cardiologist</span>
        <span class="userlistspan1 tt-Userss">SPECIALITY</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="userlistspan tt-User" data-value="2">Cardio</span>
        <span class="userlistspan1 tt-Userss">SPECIALITY</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

From there you can attach the click handler to the `.userlistspan` class, and use the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event. You can then use the `data()` method to get the `data-value`, like this:

```
$('#userlist li .userlistspan').click(function() { 
    var $span = $(this);
    $('#txtSearch').val($span.text());
    var value = $span.data('value'); // = 1 or 2, depending on which element you clicked.
})
```

Comment: userlistspan not an class it is Id so how i can find the value

Comment: @Muthu you have to change it a class as you cannot have duplicate ids